# In Typescript, Is it possible to declare "type" from an existing object?

Tags: typescript

Say, I have a function like this:

```
function plus(a: number, b: number) { return a + b }
```

Of course, it's type is `(a: number, b: number) => number` as function in Typescript.

If I want to use this function as an "argument" for another without really declare its type, I could use the default argument trick:

```
function wrap(fn = plus) { ... }
```

If I don't want it to be the default argument, **do I have any other choice besides explicitly declare its type ?**

In short, I don't want this `function wrap(fn: (a: number, b: number) => number) { ... }`, but I do want something like this `function wrap(fn: like(plus)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @OweR ReLoaDeD, `type fn = typeof plus` is a valid statement, so this works:

```
function plus(a: number, b: number) { return a + b }
function wrap(fn: typeof plus) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

What about using generics:

```
function plus(a: number, b: number) { return a + b }

function wrap<T extends Function>(fn: T) {
    fn();
}

// Works 
var wrappedPlus = wrap<typeof plus>(plus);

// Error: Argument of type '5' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number, b: number) => number'.
var wrappedPlus = wrap<typeof plus>(5);

// Error: Argument of type '5' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'.
var wrappedPlus = wrap(5);

function concat(a: string, b: string) { return a + b }

// Error: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: string, b: string) => string'.
var wrappedPlus = wrap<typeof concat>(plus);
```

Comment: Just realized that `type fn = typeof plus` is a valid statement. I over simplified the question, actually I want to use something with a higher-order function, and in that case I don't think `typeof` will work anymore. Thank you so much by the way.